# Code review: infix to postfix converter

Tags: java, strings, stack, converting

```
public static StringBuffer infixToPostfix(StringBuffer infix) throws InvalidCharacterException
        {
            StringBuffer postfix = new StringBuffer("");


        Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<String>();
        myStack.push("(");
        infix.append(')');

        for(int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
        {

            if(infix.charAt(i) == ' ')
            {
                //System.out.println("Space!");
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(infix.charAt(i)) == true)
            {
                postfix.append(infix.charAt(i) + " ");
            }
            else if(infix.charAt(i) == '(')
            {
                myStack.push("(");
            }
            else if(infix.charAt(i) == ')')
            {

                while(myStack.peek()!="(")
                {
                    postfix.append(myStack.pop() + " ");

                }
                myStack.pop();
            }
            else if(isOperator(infix.charAt(i) + "") == true)
            {
                String peekedItem = myStack.peek();

                if(isOperator(peekedItem) == true)
                {

                    if(getPrecedence(infix.charAt(i) + "") <= getPrecedence(peekedItem))
                    {
                        String poppedOp = myStack.pop();
                        if(poppedOp == "+")
                        {
                            postfix.append("+ ");
                        }

                        else if(poppedOp == "-")
                        {
                            postfix.append("- ");
                        }

                        else if(poppedOp == "*")
                        {
                            postfix.append("* ");
                        }

                        else if(poppedOp == "/")
                        {
                            postfix.append("/ ");
                        }

                        else if(poppedOp == "%")
                        {
                            postfix.append("% ");
                        }


                        String op = String.valueOf(infix.charAt(i));
                        myStack.push(op);
                    }
                }
                else if(isOperator(peekedItem)==false)
                {
                    String op = String.valueOf(infix.charAt(i));
                    myStack.push(op);
                }

            }
            else
                throw new InvalidCharacterException(infix.charAt(i));
        }

        return postfix;
    }



public static double evaluatePost(StringBuffer postfix)
    {
        String str = new String(postfix);

        str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");

        postfix = new StringBuffer(str);
        postfix.append(")");

        Stack<Double> anotherStack = new Stack<Double>();

        double answer = 0;
        for(int k = 0; postfix.charAt(k) != ')'; k++)
        {

            if(Character.isDigit(postfix.charAt(k)) == true)
            {
                anotherStack.push(Double.parseDouble(postfix.charAt(k)+""));

            }
            else if(isOperator(postfix.charAt(k)+"")==true)
            {
                double x = anotherStack.pop();


                double y = anotherStack.pop();


                char op = postfix.charAt(k);


                if(op=='+')
                {
                    answer = (x+y);
                    anotherStack.push(answer);
                    answer = 0;
                }

                else if(op=='-')
                {
                    answer = (y-x);
                    anotherStack.push(answer);
                    answer = 0;
                }

                else if(op=='*')
                {
                    answer = (x*y);
                    anotherStack.push(answer);
                    answer = 0;
                }

                else if(op=='/')
                {
                    answer = (y/x);
                    anotherStack.push(answer);
                    answer = 0;
                }

                else if(op=='%')
                {
                    answer = (x%y);
                    anotherStack.push(answer);
                    answer = 0;
                }

            }

        }
        double finalAnswer = anotherStack.pop();

        return finalAnswer;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing String comparisons, **DO NOT USE `==` **

Change your lines:

```
if(poppedOp == "+") {
     postfix.append("+ ");
}
.....
```

to be

```
if("+".equals(poppedOp)) {
     postfix.append("+ ");
}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of those cascade ifs, use switches

Replace all the `if(foo == true)` with `if(foo)`